# re call api in fragment android kotlin and perform searchView

Tags: android, kotlin

the question is similar on [Where should I call Rest API in fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62171730/where-should-i-call-rest-api-in-fragment)

but i want to discuss about the right on code.

i have call an api from `oncreateView()`
for example

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            showHomeViewModel("someState")
        }
}
```

in function `showHomeViewModel()` i have defined condition for adapter

```
private suspend fun showHomeViewModel(state: String) {
  withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    viewModel.liveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, observer)

    if(adapter.itemCount == 0) callApi() else Log.d(TAG_LOG, "nothing todo")
  }
}
```

so its calling if the data == 0

but i have `searchView` component , when i navigate to other fragment and back to first fragment , the observer is **null**...

```
    private val observer =
        Observer<MutableList<DataItem>> { item ->
            Log.d(TAG_LOG, "observer data $item") // always null if i have ever navigate to other fragment
            if (item != null)
                adapter.setData(item)
            binding.progress.gone()
        }
```

the problem is solve when i remove the condition `adapter.itemCount == 0`.
but the lifecycle my device always call api when screen or fragment appear.

before i always put the callApi from `onResume()`, but in my course should i put to the `onCreateView` and other explain should in `onViewCreate()` but the main problem is , **its good the code if i use the condition `adapter.itemCount == 0` ? to perform searachView , where i defined on viewModel for search (liveData) **

i was tried to from adapter `Filterable` to perform search but its not work with liveData, so i use my viewModel instead of filterable.